# logarithmic return type search inside factory

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following situation

```
struct Base {};
struct A : Base;
struct B : Base;
struct C : Base;
struct D : Base;
....
Base* createFromIndex(size_t index) {
    if (0 == index) return new A();
    if (1 == index) return new B();
    if (2 == index) return new C();
    ....
}
```

I wonder if the amount of `Base` children becomes large enough is there any way to make the function quicker? E.g. is there any way to implement a binary search besides hardcoding binary search decision tree?

Comment: @Thomas, Well, what value type for a hash map will you offer?

Comment: Quicker or more elegant?

Comment: @Chiel, I understand how to do this in O(1) time but is's really dirty so there would be a preference for elegancy:)

Comment: Looks like you might want a factory pattern

Comment: O(1)? either it's O(n) or O(log n). If you can implement the O(1), use it anyway :-

Comment: That IS a factory already, Nathan. If they are compile time constants, switch (and compiler optimization) is good (see axalis's answer). Or you can register each sub-generator in std::map<int, gen-function-ptr-type> to use up time and memory once, and get O(1) for every lookup.

Comment: if by elegant, you mean "easy to understand and maintain" then yes, there is a preference.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Ah yes.  I always think it of in terms like dasblinkenlight's answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use `switch` - in most compilers it is implemented as a jump table (O(1)) for close range values (seems to be your case) and as "linked branches" for wider ranges (binary search, O(log N)).

See also here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem

And regarding the code elegance and readability - use of `switch` is usually working pretty well in those regards.

Other than that, as others mentioned, you can create factory for each class (which will take care of constructing each particular class) and store the factory instances in a hash map (or directly in an array - a lookup table). then again you can call the factory by index with O(1).

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to implement a binary search besides hardcoding binary search decision tree?

One approach is to make a `std::map` of `std::function` producing your objects, like this:

```
std::map<int,std::function<Base*()>> genById = {
    {1, std::function<Base*()>([]() {return new A;})}
,   {2, std::function<Base*()>([]() {return new B;})}
,   {3, std::function<Base*()>([]() {return new C;})}
};
```

Now your dispatch is completely declarative - no additional code is required. You can instantiate your object in a single line, and use `std::map`'s fast lookup, like this:

```
int main() {
    Base *obj = genById[3]();
    obj->run();
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SFkSyl)